# Cannot debug app on Xcode 7.1 beta, with iOS 9.0 GM

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7.1beta

I am getting the following error when trying to run my app using Xcode 7.1 Beta (7B60) with iOS 9.0 GM installed on my iPad:

> An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.
>
> Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000076)

Is there a fix for this issue ? Apple developer forum has one related post , but with no solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to run iOS 9.1 beta together with Xcode 7.1 beta. Using a GM iOS and a beta Xcode together leads to this kind of problems.

I'd suggest to simply use Xcode 7.0 GM with your installed version of iOS.

Comment: What if I get this error, and I'm not using an Xcode beta?