# Cannot connect iPad with iOS 9 to XCode 7.1 (Beta 7B60)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I keep getting the following error on XCode 7.1 (beta), for an iPad running on iOS 9:

> **An error was encountered while enabling development on this device.**
>   Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE8000076)

I have tried restarting both device and XCode, dis- and reconnecting them, multiple times. I changed XCode Preferences->Locations->Command Line Tools to XCode 7.1 as it has been suggested for a similar situation: [iphone-wont-connect-in-xcode-6-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233220/iphone-wont-connect-in-xcode-6-beta)

None of the above helps. Any idea?

Comment: Stupid suggestion, but it got me once. For me I needed to set up the device in iTunes first! If it has already been set up, maybe delete the profile and re-setup?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The device has already been setup. On iTunes I don't see much option, I do not want to reset & setup the iPad. Playing with profiles won't help either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605563/cannot-debug-app-on-xcode-7-1-beta-with-ios-9-0-gm The recommendation there is to use Xcode 7 GM.

Comment: I have the same problem but i have ios9.1 and xcode7.1, both from the store

Comment: For me, it had been set up in iTunes months back, but after opening up iTunes, selecting the device, and rejecting the prompt to upgrade it, only then would Xcode's Devices Organizer start re-downloading Symbol Files, and eventually it worked.