# iOS running app from xcode show me a message to enable debug logging

Tags: ios, xcode

when I start my app from xcode 7 I see this message

```
2016-01-14 13:50:13.119 Guggy[31879:] <GMR/INFO> To enable debug logging      
set the following application argument: -GMRDebugEnabled (see  http://goo.gl/Y0Yjwu)
```

I tried to follow their instructions in the link but it still show me this message.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See if you can work this out for yourself. Try following that link. It tells you how to set arguments on your program.

Comment: [check this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605563/cannot-debug-app-on-xcode-7-1-beta-with-ios-9-0-gm)

Comment: @the_UB I'm using xcode Version 7.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong.

The message " To enable debug logging ..." is always showing up regardless if you have the debug logging enabled or not.

If you want to check whether you enabled the debug logging, you should look for the following message: " Debug logging enabled".

Use -noGMRDebugEnabled to disable the debug logging.